facebook/m2m100_418M model - how to translate longer sequences of text
I have this extracted the following text from Wikipedia's Wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki),
A wiki is a form of hypertext publication on the internet which is collaboratively edited and managed by its audience directly through a web browser. A typical wiki contains multiple pages that can either be edited by the public or limited to use within an organization for maintaining its internal knowledge base.

Wikis are powered by wiki software, also known as wiki engines. Being a form of content management system, these differ from other web-based systems such as blog software or static site generators in that the content is created without any defined owner or leader. Wikis have little inherent structure, allowing one to emerge according to the needs of the users. Wiki engines usually allow content to be written using a lightweight markup language and sometimes edited with the help of a rich-text editor. There are dozens of different wiki engines in use, both standalone and part of other software, such as bug tracking systems. Some wiki engines are free and open-source, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access); for example, editing rights may permit changing, adding, or removing material. Others may permit access without enforcing access control. Further rules may be imposed to organize content. In addition to hosting user-authored content, wikis allow those users to interact, hold discussions, and collaborate.

and tried to translate it to French, in the way shown in the model card and found some part of the text to be discarded from the translation.
This is the French translation I got,
Un wiki est une forme de publication hypertexte sur Internet qui est collaborativement édité et géré par son public directement par le biais d'un navigateur Web. Un wiki typique contient plusieurs pages qui peuvent soit être édité par le public ou limité à utiliser dans une organisation pour maintenir sa base de connaissances interne. Wikis sont alimentées par le logiciel wiki, également connu sous le nom de moteurs wiki. Être une forme de système de gestion du contenu, ces derniers diffèrent d'autres systèmes web tels que le logiciel de blog ou les générateurs de site statiques dans lequel le contenu est créé sans propriétaire ou leader défini. Wikis ont peu de structure inhérente, permettant à l'un d'émerger en fonction des besoins des utilisateurs. Les moteurs wiki permettent généralement le contenu

and English version of that according to google-translate is, (I wanted to verify the translation since I don't know French)
A wiki is a form of hypertext publication on the Internet that is collaboratively edited and managed by its audience directly through a web browser. A typical wiki contains multiple pages that can either be edited by the public or restricted to use within an organization to maintain its internal knowledge base. Wikis are powered by wiki software, also known as wiki engines. Being a form of content management system, these differ from other web systems such as blogging software or static site generators in which content is created without a defined owner or leader. Wikis have little inherent structure, allowing one to emerge based on user needs. Wiki engines typically allow content

So, as can be seen from both (from facebook/m2m100_418M and google-translate) the translation from the m2m100_418M is shorter and I presume because the input was truncated because of model's ability.
How to translate longer sequences using this pretrained model? and if the option is to feed shorter sequences in a loop, how to find the threshold at which sentences end or to not let the context get lost, not at a character limit?
Here is my code:
>>> # translate Hindi to French
>>> tokenizer.src_lang = "eng"
>>> # `inp_text` variable has the text from above
>>> inp_encoded = tokenizer(inp_text, return_tensors="pt")
>>> generated_tokens = model.generate(**inp_encoded, forced_bos_token_id=tokenizer.get_lang_id("fr"))
>>> tokenizer.batch_decode(generated_tokens, skip_special_tokens=True)


Could you show some code of what you did to get the translation? You will have to disable (or specify a larger) max_length before truncation in the tokenizer and the generation, which usually involves passing some extra arguments. The details depend on how you run the translations, e.g. through model.generate() or through a translation pipeline. Check out this repository for an example on how to specify a max_length when using generate(): https://github.com/EliasK93/transformer-models-for-domain-specific-machine-translation/blob/master/domain_specific_machine_translation/model_utils.py#L66.

I have added code, it is from the huggingface code, I had not made any changes. Thanks for the github repo link to show how to add max length for tokens. I have been using model.generate(), not the pipeline way.

How do you suggest I break long paragraphs of text for translation using facebook/m2m100_418M and facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M? How to find the optimum break points so I don't lose any context?

If you only want to use the model for inference (and therefore you only have monolingual input data) you could use any popular text segmentation approach. A simple way would be to use something like SpaCy's sentencizer, LangChains Textsplitters or langtrain-aligners split_by_sentences_wrapper. I am not aware of any approach that specifically keeps as much context as possible for translation, but my guess would just to maximize the chunk size your GPU can handle.

E.g. say you set the limit to 1024 tokens, then do the sentence splitting with one of the mentioned approaches and concatenate sentences until it exceeds that token limit in a while loop or so. This way you always keep as much context as possible. A more complex approach could be to segment sequences of sentences into groups of semantically similar topics, but this seems like a non-trivial problem where you would need another LLM-based approach.

Thank you so much @EliasK93, I shall try SpaCy's Sentencizer.
